# Cypress unable to save current URL with `as`

Tags: url, cypress

My web app generates a UUIDv4 for every new 'post', and each post has its own URL like `/posts/<uuid>`. I'm not able to predict what uuid gets generated, and therefore I'm unable to go back to a specific post that was created earlier during testing.

According to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url), `cy.url()` returns the URL as a string. I tried saving the URL using a `.as()`, but it didn't work:

```
cy.url().as('postUrl');
// go somewhere else
cy.visit('@postUrl');

// ends up visiting `localhost:3000/@postUrl`
```

I saw in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790303/cy-url-and-or-cy-locationhref-does-not-return-a-string) that I should use `.then` on `cy.url()`, but that didn't work either:

```
cy.url().then(url => url).as('postUrl');
// go somewhere else
cy.visit('@postUrl');
```

How do I save the current URL for use later?

Answer (score 3):

Found the [answer](https://www.stevenhicks.me/blog/2020/02/working-with-variables-in-cypress-tests/) buried in later pages of a google search. In order to use the saved URL, use `cy.get('@postUrl')` and call a `.then` with a callback that visits that url.

```
cy.url().as('postUrl');
// go somewhere else
cy.get('@postUrl').then(url => {
  cy.visit(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentUrl=''

cy.url().then(url => {
    currentUrl = url;
});

cy.visit(currentUrl)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.